# Java runtime not found in OSX 10.9.1 while running solR

Tags: java, macos, solr

I want to run solR in mac OSX 10.9.1. So I installed JRE latest version. Then, I downloaded solR and expanded the folder. But when I try to run this jar file in example folder, I get this msg "no java runtime present", mentioned below.

Do I need to add JAVA_HOME env variable like we do in windows? If so, please tell me how.

```
Ananyas-MacBook-Pro:~ ananya$  /Library/Internet\ Plug-Ins/JavaAppletPlugin.plugin/Contents/Home/bin/java -version 
java version "1.7.0_51"  
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build
1.7.0_51-b13) 
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.51-b03, mixed mode) 
Ananyas-MacBook-Pro:~ ananya$ cd /Users/ananya/Desktop/VT\ study/solr-4.6.1/example 
Ananyas-MacBook-Pro:example ananya$ java -jar start.jar 
No Java runtime present, requesting install. 
Ananyas-MacBook-Pro:example ananya$
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

**"Do I need to add JAVA_HOME env variable like we do in windows?"**

Test to see if/where Java is on your path in a terminal:

```
echo $JAVA_HOME
```

If the path to Java is wrong or missing you can add and [Environmental Variable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Environment_variable) to ~/.bash_profile like so

```
JAVA_HOME=/usr/bin/java  #or whatever your path is
export PATH=$PATH:$JAVA_HOME/bin/
```

You can open ~/.bash_profile in a terminal with [nano](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/42980/the-beginners-guide-to-nano-the-linux-command-line-text-editor/)

```
nano ~/.bash_profile.
```

**Nano hint:** `writeout` means save.

You'll need to reopen your terminal to load the new path. Or, reload it with the [source](http://ss64.com/osx/source.html) command.

```
source ~/.bash_profile
```

Alternatively, if you like saving keystrokes you can type

```
. ~/.bash_profile
```

Comment: can you post the results of "echo $JAVA_HOME" ?

Comment: Then Java is not on your path. Mine returns `/usr/bin/java` Can you put your ~/.bash_profile in your post?

Comment: Its empty. Do I need to put anything in that?

Comment: Add to it just like I said in the answer. You can open it in a terminal with `nano ~/.bash_profile`. Nano hint "writeout" means save".

Comment: I added the path in bash profile. Even then when I try to run solR, it says "No java runtime present"

Comment: so if you type `java -version` in a terminal java gives you it's info, right?

Comment: no it doesn't. it says "no java runtime present". Anyways...I got pissed off. So installed JRE and running SolR in my windows pc. Thanks for your time, btw :)

Comment: Well that means that in spite of your attempts you still don't have java on your path. If you put the contents of `cat ~/.bash_profile` into your post I can help you fix it.

Comment: I installed JRE following the solution in this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19533528/installing-java-on-os-x-10-9-mavericks

Comment: But then when I try to run any java application, I get this error 

Error occurred during initialization of VM
Could not find agent library: libcalljvmti.jnilib (searched /System/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/Contents/Libraries:/System/Library/Java/Extensions:/Library/Java/Extensions:.)