# Eclipse not Launching in OS X Mavericks? (Not a single bounce or error message!)

Tags: java, eclipse, macos, osx-mavericks

When I try launching Eclipse in Mavericks it does nothing. Neither activity monitor nor console reflect my attempt to launch it in anyway. The icon doesn't bounce. No errors show up. No error sound. Just nothing.

I have a few other programs exhibiting these same symptoms, such as NetExtender.

This is on a 2012 MBP (non Retina) with the version of Mavericks that was released to everyone through the MAS on October 22nd, 2013 (build 13A603... OS X 10.9.0).

Eclipse is version 4.3
NetExtender is version 6.0.719

Googling around, some people are suggesting the issue is with Java in Mavericks. I downloaded and installed the latest JDK (7.45) but that doesn't seem to have helped in anyway.

Comment: try starting it from the commmand line. It will print information there if there's a reason it is not launching. Also double check your java home when you launch eclipse; it might actually try to use the apple version instead of the oracle. Also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1348842/what-should-i-set-java-home-to-on-osx

Comment: As a follow up on my NetExtender issue, I should mention that simply getting Java SE 6 wasn't enough. The app's UI would appear but it would error out. I had IT look around and they found a newer version, 6.0.752, which properly works with Mavericks. I mention this just for incase anyone arrives here after Googling about NetExtender and Mavericks.

Comment: Note that Eclipse 4.4 does not work with Java 6 any more.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

There should be a popup asking you to install a Java SE 6 runtime.

It didn't appear for me either at first but that might have been because some other windows was covering it, so I saw it when I restarted the computer, and it appeared again when opening eclipse after the restart.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Hi - You're right, when I closed all of the windows on screen there was a popup all the way at the back. This is definitely a bug that needs to be reported to Apple.

Comment: I have reported this usability issue to Apple. The issue number is 15309783.

Comment: Accepted - you answered first and were correct that the popup was appearing, but behind other windows.

Comment: @ArtOfWarfare Thanks for reporting the usability issue, the same issue was driving me nuts as well.

Comment: I find it amusing that all of DAVID's rep has come from this single answer. 250 rep from upvotes, plus 15 for being accepted, plus the 1 that you start with for joining SO.

Answer (score 9):

If you launch eclipse with the Terminal with:

```
   open Eclipse.app
```

and you get an "LSOpenURLsWithRole() failed with error -10810 for the file..." then you have to make the eclipse executable file *actually* executable.

```
   chmod +x Eclipse.app/Contents/MacOS/eclipse
```

That worked for me!

Comment: I would imagine this is very rarely a problem... why would Eclipse not be marked as an executable?

Comment: This worked for me! Wow... this was a recent build of Eclipse LUNA too.

Comment: I have to use this chmod command to make it work.  I'm running OS 10.8.5 on a mac mini.  Coming from windows background, sometimes I feel mac OS is an immature operation system.  Occasionally, it just does not do something and not tell me why.

Comment: I've noticed that SCP sometimes will change files that had been marked as executables will change them to no longer have the executable flag on RHEL and Cent... maybe this also happens on OS X sometimes? I've never seen it myself.

Answer (score 3):

Upgrading from LUNA to MARS - http://download.eclipse.org/releases/mars  -  I ended up with the same error -10810.

The Eclipse.app file had been corrupted and and was actually missing some of the package parts.

Thankfully, I had Time Machine running and just restored the previous version of the Eclipse.app file. Eclipse opened up fine.

Answer (score 2):

If you are not prompted for it, Java 6 (1.6.0_65) can be installed on your system using this [link](http://support.apple.com/kb/DL1572?viewlocale=en_US).

On a few of our systems an old and unusable but required (do not attempt to delete it!) version 1.6.0_45 remained after Mavericks upgrade.

Comment: Our project requires Java 7... will installing this copy of Java 6 somehow interfere with it (we use Java on the backend, but I mostly work on the frontend portion in a variety of other languages.)

Comment: +1 for the link, but DAVID provided essentially the same answer a few minutes quicker. Thank you.

Comment: On Mavericks you need to install a 64bit version of Eclipse for it to run under offical jdk7 releases. And possibly edit the JNI settings.

Answer (score 0):

This is specific to NIEM_UML version of Eclipse. When I double clicked on NIEM_UML.app on my Mac, it ended with a message that read "LSOpenURLsWithRole() failed for the application /Users//Desktop/NIEM/NIEM_UML.app with error -10810." I had to make set the executable property as below: chmod +x ./NIEM_UML.app/Contents/MacOS/niem_uml