# How to set JAVA_HOME environment variable on Mac OS X 10.9?

Tags: java, macos, osx-mavericks

I just purchased a brand new MacBook Pro.

This is my first MAC ever and I'm still trying to get the hang of navigating my way around.

Anyway, I'm also new to Java and I've been practicing on my Windows PC before it permanently died.

Now that I'm on this MAC, I installed my JDK and now I need to set the `JAVA_HOME` environment variable.

I have no idea what to do.

I tried following some of these guides and didn't get very far.

1. **[Mkyong.com : How to set JAVA_HOME variable in Mac OSX](http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-set-java_home-environment-variable-on-mac-os-x/)**
2. **[YouTube : How to set environment variables on mac, linux, solaris, rhel](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aCEPrODy68o)**
3. **[YouTube : How to Set Environment Variables in Mac](http://youtube.com/watch?v=-cASjkF94dc)**

I was able to locate the terminal and I think I created some multiple files. I'm getting messages like this:

---

> (1) Another program may be editing the same file.
>       If this is the case, be careful not to end up with two
>       different instances of the same file when making changes.
>       Quit, or continue with caution.

---

> (2) An edit session for this file crashed.
>       If this is the case, use ":recover" or "vim -r /Users/Erwin/.bash_profile"
>       to recover the changes (see ":help recovery").
>       If you did this already, delete the swap file "/Users/Erwin/.bash_profile.sw p"
>       to avoid this message.

Can somebody tell how to set Java in Mac OSX environment step by step?

Comment: Duplicate of: http://superuser.com/questions/240100/setting-java-home-environment-variable

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What should I set JAVA\_HOME to on OSX](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1348842/what-should-i-set-java-home-to-on-osx)

Comment: briefly explain:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/59151321/5788247

Comment: After installing via `brew` on an M1 Mac, mine was located `/opt/homebrew/Cellar/openjdk/17.0.1_1/libexec/openjdk.jdk/Contents/Home`. Obviously change for your version but the typical methods of finding the path proved difficult so I hope this helps others.

Comment: Don't forget to restart the terminal in mac after setting any environment variable, else you keep seeing the unset values

Answer (score 598, accepted):

If you're using bash, all you have to do is:

```
echo export "JAVA_HOME=\$(/usr/libexec/java_home)" >> ~/.bash_profile
```

If you're using zsh (which probably means you're running macOS Catalina or newer), then it should instead be:

```
echo export "JAVA_HOME=\$(/usr/libexec/java_home)" >> ~/.zshrc
```

In either case, restart your shell.

If you have multiple JDK versions installed and you want it to be a specific one, you can use the `-v` flag to `java_home` like so:

```
echo export "JAVA_HOME=\$(/usr/libexec/java_home -v 1.7)" >> ~/.bash_profile
```

Comment: When you say "shell," do you mean I close the terminal window and reopen it? Also, does this permanently add the environment variable for my jdk?

Comment: Yes, that's what I mean. And yes, that will add the variable for all login shells for your user (i.e, pretty much all of the circumstances in which you would want it)

Comment: I think instead of restarting the terminal if you do `source ~/.bash_profile` it would work, right?

Comment: @ShobhitPuri Yup, it would, I just wanted to keep it simple for the asker.

Comment: Is there some sort of reference document from which this black magic can be obtained? (Answer: yes. 'man java_home'. Apparently part of Xcode. ('xcode-select -p' to determine whether you have it.)) Me: another Mac noob.

Comment: `echo export "JAVA_HOME=\$(/usr/libexec/java_home -v 1.7)" >> ~/.bash_profile` If you need a specific version. 1.7 in this case.

Comment: Will this update to the latest version with future java updates? Or do you need to re-run each time?

Comment: @Rarw: If you put this in your `~/.bash_profile`, it'll run every time you log in. So, no need to change anything :)

Comment: the `export` content didnt work for my Mac. Running Catalina in 2020 another answer worked for me

Comment: Before doing this, check the shell that you are using echo $SHELL....

If it is zsh, instead of bash_profile, you would have to use .zshenv or .zshrc

Comment: on OSX 11. Instead of bash profile, we're now using `.zshrc`. So the command will be `echo export "JAVA_HOME=\$(/usr/libexec/java_home)" >> ~/.zshrc`

Comment: `~/.bash_profile` does not work on macOS Monterey version 12.0. `echo export "JAVA_HOME=\$(/usr/libexec/java_home)" >> ~/.zshrc` can work.

Comment: I received the message after run this command 
echo export "JAVA_HOME=\$(/usr/libexec/java_home)" >> ~/.zshrc
source .zshrc

.zshrc:export:118: JAVA_HOME: inconsistent type for assignment

Comment: we must source the bash zsh file.

Comment: In macOS Ventura, it's ~/.zprofile

Comment: To check which Shell one is using, use echo $0 and then enter. After adding the path, to exit the vim, press the esp Key, then press : (colon) and type x & hit Enter. This will save the changes and exit. Then use source ~/.bash_profile or source ~/.zprofile depending on your shell to save all changes

Comment: In MacOS **Monterrey** I'm still using `~/.bash_profile` so perhaps it's advisable to follow what @Jerry Chong says and run first `$ echo $SHELL` to know what shell you're using. If it's `/bin/bash` then follow @Adrian Petrescu

Comment: You can use `source ~/.zshrc` instead of restarting the terminal

Answer (score 142):

I just spent 2 hours setting this variable. The other answers did not work properly for me. I'm using macOS Catalina 10.15.4.

First, find your actual Java SDK Home directory:

```
/usr/libexec/java_home
```

Manually navigate there to make sure you don't have any mistakes due to incorrect versions, etc. For me, this was:

```
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-13.0.2.jdk/Contents/Home
```

Next, edit your terminal's profile. If you're using zsh, this will be:

```
vim ~/.zshrc
```

If you're not using zsh, this will be:

```
vim ~/.bash_profile
```

Inside, add the following new line anywhere in the file:

```
export JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-13.0.2.jdk/Contents/Home
```

Restart your terminal app (or source ~/.bash_profile), and it should work properly.

Comment: Thank you.  This worked for me on MacOS BigSur

Comment: I had the same experience, and this got it solved for me.  Thanks!

Comment: This worked even on macOS Monterey. Thanks for this one! Appreciate it!

Comment: To find your JAVA SDK Home directory, you can run these commands too:
For MAC OS: echo $JAVA_HOME
For Windows: echo %JAVA_HOME%

Comment: I ran `brew update` and `brew upgrade` which updated my JDK minor version. This caused my `JAVA_HOME` value to be wrong. Correcting the path to match the new version caused it to work fine now.

Comment: this works for me on i use macOS Monterey version 12.66.8

Answer (score 58):

I did it by putting

```
export JAVA_HOME=`/usr/libexec/java_home`
```

(backtics) in my .bashrc.  See my comment on Adrian's answer.

Additionally update PATH variable as well.

```
PATH=$PATH:$JAVA_HOME/bin
```

Comment: Slightly more modern way: `export JAVA_HOME="$(/usr/libexec/java_home)"`

Answer (score 46):

## Set **$JAVA_HOME** environment variable on latest or older Mac OSX.

**Download & Install install [JDK](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html)**

1. First, install JDK
2. Open terminal check java version

> `$ java -version`

**Set JAVA_HOME environment variable**

1. Open **.zprofile** file

> `$ open -t .zprofile`

Or create **. zprofile** file

> $ `open -t .zprofile`

2. write in .zprofile

> `export JAVA_HOME=$(/usr/libexec/java_home)`

**Save .zprofile** and close the bash file & then write in the terminal for work **perfectly**.

```
$ source .zprofile
```

Setup test in terminal

```
$ echo $JAVA_HOME  
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-13.0.1.jdk/Contents/Home
```

Comment: Also I had a question what "/usr/libexec/java_home" actually is. Answer:
https://medium.com/zendesk-engineering/setting-java-home-on-mac-os-acd44e3a6027

Comment: /usr/libexec/java_home is the simplest maintainable way of setting JAVA_HOME on macOS. You can use java_home to: Find all installed JDKs.

Comment: this works for me on a 2019 Mac running Catalina in 2020. Accepted and most upvoted answer didn't. First thing is that the bash profile is now `.zprofile`, also the `export` command content in accepted answer didn't work for me but this did.

Comment: Just a note about where to get the JDK from–alternatively, you can install JDK from https://adoptopenjdk.net/. The difference is that Oracle's licence does not allow commercial builds using its JDK unless you pay for the licence. Whereas adoptopenjdk is open source.

Comment: ```export PATH="${JAVA_HOME}/bin:$PATH"```

Answer (score 36):

In Mac OSX 10.5 or later, Apple recommends to set the `$JAVA_HOME variable to /usr/libexec/java_home`, just export `$JAVA_HOME` `in file ~/.bash_profile` or `~/.profile`.

Open the terminal and run the below command.

```
$ vim .bash_profile

export JAVA_HOME=$(/usr/libexec/java_home)
```

Save and exit from Vim editor, then run the `source` command on `.bash_profile`

```
$ source .bash_profile

$ echo $JAVA_HOME

/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.7.0.jdk/Contents/Home
```

Answer (score 27):

It is recommended to check **default terminal shell** before set **JAVA_HOME** environment variable, via following commands:

```
$ echo $SHELL
/bin/bash
```

If your default terminal is **/bin/bash** (Bash), then you should use **@Adrian Petrescu** method.

If your default terminal is **/bin/zsh** (Z Shell), then you should set these environment variable in **~/.zshenv** file with following contents:

```
export JAVA_HOME="$(/usr/libexec/java_home)"
```

Similarly, any other terminal type not mentioned above, you should set environment variable in its respective terminal env file.

Comment: ```export JAVA_HOME=$(/usr/libexec/java_home)
export PATH="${JAVA_HOME}/bin:$PATH"```

Answer (score 12):

Quick Guide for M1

1. Add java sdk into your m1
   check version

   java --version

Get all java versions installed in ur mac

```
/usr/libexec/java_home -V
```

2. Execute for Java path from library

   /usr/libexec/java_home

(specify java version if you have multiple version, In my case -v17.0.5

```
/usr/libexec/java_home -v17.0.5
```

3. Mac>User>'YourUserName/Home'>.zshrc

   export JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-17.0.5.jdk/Contents/Home

Comment: this works best for M1!

Answer (score 7):

If you are using Zsh, then try to add this line in ~/.zshrc file & restart terminal.

```
export JAVA_HOME=$(/usr/libexec/java_home)
```

Answer (score 5):

JAVA 11 via Homebrew - tested on macos Ventura 2022

.zshrc

```
export JAVA_HOME=/opt/homebrew/opt/openjdk@11/libexec/openjdk.jdk/Contents/Home
```

Answer (score 4):

I got it working by adding to ~/.profile. Somehow after updating to El Capitan beta, it didnt work even though JAVA_HOME was defined in .bash_profile.

If there are any El Capitan beta users, try adding to .profile

Comment: What's the difference between .profile and .bash_profile?

Comment: The idea is that .profile runs for all shells (sh, zsh, whatever); .bash_profile, only for bash shells.

Answer (score 3):

**For Mac M1**

**Download & Install install JDK**

**Open terminal check java version**

`java -version`

Now create a file

`touch .zprofile`

Open the file

`open -t .zprofile`

Add the below line

`export JAVA_HOME=$(/usr/libexec/java_home)`

Answer (score 3):

More simply on a mac terminal with a modern OSX

```
$ vim ~/.zshrc
```

Type "a" to being editing, and then paste (ctrl + v):

```
$ JAVA_HOME=/usr/libexec/java_home
```

then hit "escape" and type exactly ":wq" in order to write to the file and quit vim mode.

Finally, when out of vim mode and back in your terminal, type

```
$ source ~/.zshrc
```

This will refresh so that your terminal is aware of the changes.

- IMPORTANT *  If you don't "source" the file, you won't see the changes in this terminal session.

Check the changes by typing

```
$ echo $JAVA_HOME
```

and you should see `/usr/libexec/java_home`

Comment: Please correct: `JAVA_HOME=/usr/libexec/java_home` should be `export JAVA_HOME=$(/usr/libexec/java_home)`

Comment: There was a typo @MarkHu. I fixed it. Apologies, and thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 1):

Since I'm using openjdk managed with sdkman, I added

```
sudo ln -sfn /path/to/my/installed/jdk/openjdk.jdk /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/openjdk.jdk
```

Adding this to your system lets `java_home` recognize your installed version of Java even when its not installed via standard packages

Comment: What do you set JAVA_HOME to in this case, please? `export JAVA_HOME="/usr/libexec/java_home"` ?

Comment: With that line java will be discovered similarly to if it were a standard installation, we're linking the standard install location to point to the actual install location, so its treated like an officially installed package and you don't need to set JAVA_HOME

Answer (score 1):

In the latest Mac, you have to add the Set $JAVA_HOME environment variable in **.zprofile**. Here, we simple way to open it. Press ⌘ + Shift + . from keyboard. Just open it and add the $JAVA_HOME environment variable as explained [here](https://www.developerlibs.com/2022/06/java-environment-path-setup-windows-linux-Mac.html):

Answer (score 1):

I'm able to solve this issue by setting JAVA_HOME in .bash_profile file

```
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/local/opt/openjdk@17
```

Note:
I installed openjdk version 17 using 'brew'. I got this location from brew console. I'm using 'bash' instead of 'zsh' in my mac.

Answer (score 1):

1. i want to update JAVA_HOME variable ,so it is picked by maven in mac
2. i have used brew to install openjdk11 on my mac
3. i have a /.zshrc file in my mac

so i used below to set the JAVA_HOME to my openjdk11 -

1. vim ~/.zshrc
2. add below lines
   export=/opt/homebrew/opt/openjdk@11

Answer (score 0):

I resolved it on macOS Monterey by using the option provided by Google

Under Gradle JDK, choose the Embedded JDK option.

[https://developer.android.com/studio/intro/studio-config#:~:text=A%20copy%20of%20the%20latest,use%20for%20your%20Android%20projects](https://developer.android.com/studio/intro/studio-config#:%7E:text=A%20copy%20of%20the%20latest,use%20for%20your%20Android%20projects).

Answer (score 0):

- Open Terminal.
- Confirm you have JDK by typing “which java”. ...
- Check you have the needed version of Java, by typing
  “java -version”.
- Set JAVA_HOME using this command in Terminal: export
  JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/Home.
- echo $JAVA_HOME on Terminal to confirm
  the path.

Answer (score 0):

I had multiple versions of JDK installed, so what worked for me is that I manually configured my SpringToolSuite4 to use Java 11

Answer (score 0):

For mac users https://stackoverflow.com/a/77953587/4792285

Install using homebrew https://formulae.brew.sh/formula/openjdk

```
brew install openjdk@21
```

OR

```
brew install openjdk@11
```

Then set up the .profile on your mac (/Users/your_username/.profile). If this file is hidden you may need to press ***Command + Shift + . (the period key)*** to make it visible.

add **JAVA_HOME** and update the **PATH** variable

```
export JAVA_HOME=$(/usr/libexec/java_home)
export PATH="$JAVA_HOME:$PATH"
```

open a new terminal and type

```
echo $JAVA_HOME
echo $PATH
```

to verify your change.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/77953587/4792285