# Having trouble installing Rhodes framework on a Mac

Tags: java, ruby, macos, rhodes

When I run the command ***rake run:iphone***, I get the following error message:

**Your java bin folder does not appear to be on your path.
This is required to use rhodes.**

I've already installed JDK on my mac and have verified the java path with the command ***which java***. This is where my java is located: **/usr/bin/java**.

How can I get java on my path?

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the JAVA_HOME environment variable. Check this : https://stackoverflow.com/a/22842806/1665377

But basically, this should fix your problem :

```
echo export "JAVA_HOME=\$(/usr/libexec/java_home)" >> ~/.bash_profile
```

Then restart your shell

Comment: Would you mind accepting the answer then ?