# Permanently Setting JAVA_HOME environment variable on mac

Tags: java, android

Executing below two commands on mac Terminal which set environment variable, which is vanished on close of Terminal, any help would be appreciated

```
Step 1:- echo "export JAVA_HOME=`/usr/libexec/java_home`" >> ~/.profile 
Step 2:- . ~/.profile
```

Initial Terminal output

```
karthiks-MacBook-Air:~ karthicklove$ echo "export JAVA_HOME=`/usr/libexec/java_home`" >> ~/.profile

karthiks-MacBook-Air:~ karthicklove$ . ~/.profile

karthiks-MacBook-Air:~ karthicklove$ echo $JAVA_HOME
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_71.jdk/Contents/Home

Terminal output after closing and reopen again

karthiks-MacBook-Air:~ karthicklove$ echo $JAVA_HOME

karthiks-MacBook-Air:~ karthicklove$
```

Comment: try adding to .bash_profile

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Setting JAVA\_HOME environment variable on MAC OSX 10.9](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22842743/setting-java-home-environment-variable-on-mac-osx-10-9)

Answer (score 3):

Create a file called .bash_profile in your home directory and add the JAVA_HOME variable in it.

```
export JAVA_HOME=`/usr/libexec/java_home`
```

This file is loaded every time you open terminal or you open a new terminal tab. 
Please note that the file needs to be hidden.

Comment: Thanks issue is resolved modifying to .base_profile as below                                   
Step 1:- echo "export JAVA_HOME=`/usr/libexec/java_home`" >> ~/.bash_profile
Step 2:- . ~/.bash_profile

Comment: @VinothKumarSubramanian if you found the answer to be useful, please accept the answer with the tick.