# "Java not found" in using tabula-py

Tags: java, python, tabula

everyone, I am using tabula-py in python to extract table from pdfs. I used following codes.

```
import tabula

table_temp = tabula.read_pdf('./example_pdf/sample1.pdf',pages=11)
```

However, I got the error message as pasted below, in which I was told "no such file or directory: 'java'". I have installed Java in the following folder

```
"/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_131.jdk/Contents/Home".
```

Could anyone help me on solving the problem?

Thanks.

---

```
FileNotFoundError                         Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-4-41c9ba6fd519> in <module>()
----> 1 table_temp = tabula.read_pdf('./example_pdf/sample1.pdf',pages=11)

/Users/Myworld/anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tabula/wrapper.py in read_pdf(input_path, **kwargs)
     64 
     65     try:
---> 66         output = subprocess.check_output(args)
     67     finally:
     68         if is_url:

/Users/Myworld/anaconda/lib/python3.5/subprocess.py in check_output(timeout, *popenargs, **kwargs)
    314 
    315     return run(*popenargs, stdout=PIPE, timeout=timeout, check=True,
--> 316                **kwargs).stdout
    317 
    318 

/Users/Myworld/anaconda/lib/python3.5/subprocess.py in run(input, timeout, check, *popenargs, **kwargs)
    381         kwargs['stdin'] = PIPE
    382 
--> 383     with Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs) as process:
    384         try:
    385             stdout, stderr = process.communicate(input, timeout=timeout)

/Users/Myworld/anaconda/lib/python3.5/subprocess.py in __init__(self, args, bufsize, executable, stdin, stdout, stderr, preexec_fn, close_fds, shell, cwd, env, universal_newlines, startupinfo, creationflags, restore_signals, start_new_session, pass_fds)
    674                                 c2pread, c2pwrite,
    675                                 errread, errwrite,
--> 676                                 restore_signals, start_new_session)
    677         except:
    678             # Cleanup if the child failed starting.

/Users/Myworld/anaconda/lib/python3.5/subprocess.py in _execute_child(self, args, executable, preexec_fn, close_fds, pass_fds, cwd, env, startupinfo, creationflags, shell, p2cread, p2cwrite, c2pread, c2pwrite, errread, errwrite, restore_signals, start_new_session)
   1280                             else:
   1281                                 err_msg += ': ' + repr(orig_executable)
-> 1282                     raise child_exception_type(errno_num, err_msg)
   1283                 raise child_exception_type(err_msg)
   1284 

FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'java'
```

Comment: is the `java` executable registered in the path? if yes, you should be able to `java --version` from your os command line utility (eg. cmd, bash). what is your os anyway?

Comment: Thanks a lot for your comments. When I typed  java --version in terminal in Mac,  I got 
"-bash: java: command not found".

Comment: then you would need to put the `java/bin` directory into path that being loaded by your tools.. in ubuntu or centos, that'd be `.bashrc`. try to look on it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Setting JAVA\_HOME environment variable on MAC OSX 10.9](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22842743/setting-java-home-environment-variable-on-mac-osx-10-9)

Comment: Not clear how you installed Java, but you must update the PATH

Comment: Thanks a lot, friends.  I understand that you all suggested to reset the path for JAVA. This is to reset JAVA_HOME if I understand correctly.  In order to do that, I first check where my JAVA is installed by typing "echo $JAVA_HOME", I got "/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_131.jdk/Contents/Home". Then I typed "open -e .bash_profile" and added "export JAVA_HOME=$(/usr/libexec/java_home)" to the file and reload it.  After doing this, I thought I have correctly set path for Java. But I still got "-bash: java: command not found" when I typed java --version in terminal. Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: Hi, dear friends, I want to add that I finally solved the problem.  I not only added "export JAVA_HOME=$(/usr/libexec/java_home)" , but also "export PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH" to the .bash_profile.  And now the mac knows where Java is.  Thanks a lot for your help.

Answer (score 2):

I had run into the same error. The line actually causing the error for me was `subprocess.call('java')`.

Installing Java on my machine fixed the error for me.

If installing Java still doesn't solve the problem for you, try running `which java`, and add the output directory to your `PATH` environment variable.