# Java: Unrecognized option -loadClassifier Error Could not create the Java Virtual Machine

Tags: java

When I run a Java program on my mac i get the following error

```
$ /usr/bin/java -loadClassifier
Unrecognized option: -loadClassifier
Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.
```

When I run the program on Windows I don't get any errors.

How can i resolve this problem?

Thanks.

Comment: Did you check the `JAVA_HOME` variable?

Comment: I set JAVA_HOME as suggested in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22842743/setting-java-home-environment-variable-on-mac-osx-10-9) post, but i still get the same error.

Comment: You probably want `-D`, i.e. the argument should be `-DloadClassifier`