# JAVA_HOME Env variable on Mac OS 10.13.3

Tags: java, macos

I am using Mac book pro with Mac OS Sierra 10.13.3 version. I have installed Java 8u151 version.

Java is installed properly.

I've created the **.bash_profile** in the root directory and set the below JAVA_HOME variable.

**export JAVA_HOME=$(/usr/libexec/java_home)**

When I do: **source .bash_profile** then it is showing: **Illegal variable name**.

I've checked with my friends and they have been using Mac OS 10.12 and have not faced any issues setting up this.

Can someone help me with this?

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Setting JAVA\_HOME environment variable on MAC OSX 10.9](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22842743/setting-java-home-environment-variable-on-mac-osx-10-9)

Comment: Hi..like I said, this is working with previous versions of Mac OS not with Mac OS Sierra 10.13.3

Comment: I didn't use the $ you have on the export line

Comment: I tried it without $ and am still getting the same error.