# Error:" Unable to find any JVMs matching version "1.8"."

Tags: java, flutter

When I run flutter create x or flutter doctor I get the following message 
"Unable to find any JVMs matching version `1.8`.

I also tried following another thread on StackOverFlow for this issue but it did not help because it did not specify what to do if you already have java installed. At the moment when I run java-version I get the following message:

java version `13.0.1` 2019-10-15
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 13.0.1+9)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 13.0.1+9, mixed mode, sharing)

Thank you in advance for the help!

EDIT: I found a solution!

```
echo export "JAVA_HOME=\$(/usr/libexec/java_home -v 1.7)" >> ~/.bash_profile
```

All I did was replace 1.7 with a JDK I already had installed and now it works. The thread can be found below:

[How to set JAVA_HOME environment variable on Mac OS X 10.9?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22842743/how-to-set-java-home-environment-variable-on-mac-os-x-10-9)

Answer (score 3):

You've installed java 13 while your application is looking for java 8. So install java 8 and set it your default jvm/jre (set your JAVA_HOME).

Hope it helps !

Comment: Sorry I am new to coding and still a little confused. I just set my Java Home with this website: http://www.sajeconsultants.com/how-to-set-java_home-on-mac-os-x/?utm_source=rss&utm_medium=rss&utm_campaign=how-to-set-java_home-on-mac-os-x        .... but I did not download a different version of the JVM. Am I doing something wrong that is just a temporary fix or is what I am doing alright. Again, thanks for the help!

Comment: What I believe is that your workspace is configured to point at Java 8, however you've java 13 installed on your system. So there is a mismatch between them and thus the error.

Answer (score 1):

Just a guess, as I do not use Flutter…

## Java changed its version numbering scheme

Java changed the way it reports its own version number. In earlier versions, the number was always `1.x.y` where `x` is what we colloquially considered to be the version. Eventually Sun/Oracle decided to make that common usage official. So now later versions such as the one you are using dropped the `1.`. Rather than `1.13.y` Java now identifies itself as `13.y`.

### Update Flutter

This change in version numbering scheme can confuse old software that expected the version number to always report `1.x.y`. Such software needs to be updated to understand the new number scheme.

I suggest you update your Flutter library to a more recent updated version, if one exists.

### Downgrade Java

Most Java 8 apps should run without a problem on Java 13 if it weren't for this tiny version number interpretation issue. So you should not have to downgrade from Java 13 to Java 8 to run your app. But you might need to downgrade to resolve this issue if Flutter was never updated properly.

If you do need to downgrade, here is a flowchart I made to help locate a vendor of a Java implementation. This chart is aimed at Java 11, but most of these venders provide Java 8 implementations as well.

[image: Flowchart guiding you in choosing a vendor for a Java 11 implementation]

[image: Motivations in choosing a vendor for Java]