# Java error when I Install PROM on my Macbook

Tags: java, macos

I am trying to install ProM (process mining software) following [these instructions](http://www.promtools.org/doku.php?id=prom69)

I unzipped the package and followed the instructions:

> "On Linux and Mac OS X, you can do this by starting a shell or terminal, going to the folder where you have unpacked the archive, and by running the ProMPM69.sh file. On Mac OS X, please do not double click the ProMPM69.sh file, as this starts Xcode to edit the file instead of running it."

When I run the file from Terminal I get the following error:

```
line 31: ./jre/jre1.8.0_172.jre/Contents/Home/bin/java: No such file or directory
```

I am assuming that it is not finding Java. The file iself does the following:

```
JAVABIN=./jre/jre1.8.0_172.jre/Contents/Home/bin/java

$JAVABIN -version
$JAVABIN -classpath ${CP} -Djava.library.path=${LIBDIR} ${MAIN}`
```

Can anyone help me solve this? Thanks!

Comment: you can  install jre and set the path on mac by yourself.

Comment: Thanks, @tarun, I think I have jre installed. How do I set up the path on my mac?

Comment: This should help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22842743/how-to-set-java-home-environment-variable-on-mac-os-x-10-9

Answer (score 0):

[image]If you are using macOS using terminal to navigate to the folder where you have unzipped the ProM tool
and than run the command

in case in my folder the name is ProM610.sh and ProMPM610.sh one for package manager and other one for ProM tool UI

> sh ProM610.sh

> sh ProMPM610.sh

Hope this is useful

Please find following link for step by step guide https://medium.com/process-mining-opensource/download-and-install-prom-6-9-process-mining-tool-on-macos-e482a3c9fea0

Comment: Please include use [markdown formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) for text instead of using an image. Please also use proper punctuation.