# How to set environment variables permanently in Mac OS 10.15.6?

Tags: java, macos, environment-variables

I have tried all approaches I can find online, but none of them works.

I want to set `JAVA_HOME` and `PATH` environment variables permanently, so that in IntelliJ I can issue commands like "mvn".

I have written my script into `.bash_profile` as shown below:
[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yCW0U.png)

But after I restarted my Mac and issued `echo $JAVA_HOME`, the output is still empty.

I also tried `launchd.conf` as said in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/135688/setting-environment-variables-on-os-x), but it didn't work either.

Could someone help me here?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you using ZSH?

Comment: @AnggrayudiH Yes I think so. When I issue command `mvn -v` in the terminal, the output is `zsh: command not found: mvn`.

Comment: @AnggrayudiH Thank you so much! I just solved the problem based on the hint given by you.

Comment: @Tirion did you solve this issue? I am now having the same problem

Comment: @JaneDoe Yes. It was stupid actually. My Mac uses `zsh`, but I put the variables in the profile for `bash`... After I wrote the variables in the correct profile for zsh, it works.

Answer (score 3):

For osx add this in your `~/.profile`  or if you are using zsh inside `~/.zshrc`

```
export JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/amazon-corretto-8.jdk/Contents/Home
```

restart your terminal or simply apply your changes

```
source ~/.profile
```

refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22842743/how-to-set-java-home-environment-variable-on-mac-os-x-10-9) to know more about related to this question
& also refer [this](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/corretto/latest/corretto-8-ug/macos-install.html) to know more about installation process of Amazon Corretto 8.

If you are using zsh you can import `.profile` config inside `~/.zprofile`

```
emulate sh
. ~/.profile
emulate zsh
```

Comment: @Tirion I have updated the answer. Would you, please, try that and let me know if it works for you.

Comment: Sorry it still doesn't work. The problem is not what is the content of the `.profile` file, it is the file doesn't write anything into env variable at all. Thanks for your reply anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Check your enviroment variables with

```
env
```

then check if your config files are in the right directory. Read  `/etc/profile` e.g.

```
nano /etc/profile
```

There can you find the path to bashrc file