# Set proper path on Visual studio Code for Java on M1 MacBook Pro

Tags: java, visual-studio-code, apple-m1

so I recently got the m1 MacBook Pro and I was able to install home-brew and install java with it which installed Java-16. The problem I'm facing is how to configure java with Visual Studio Code on the m1 Mac.
When I look for java installed location `where java`
it gives me

```
/opt/homebrew/opt/openjdk/bin/java
/usr/bin/java
```

But when I put this as the path `/opt/homebrew/opt/openjdk`  in Visual Studio Code, it doesn't recognize it and gives me no jdk installed on the machine. doing `java --version` gives me

```
openjdk 17 2021-09-14
OpenJDK Runtime Environment Homebrew (build 17+0)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM Homebrew (build 17+0, mixed mode)
```

I'm confused how to configure this properly and how to find the actual path of java installed so I can configure it with Visual Studio Code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Adding the following configuration to `settings.json` makes VS Code choose the correct Homebrew JDK for my Maven projects:

```
    "java.configuration.runtimes": [
    {
      "name": "JavaSE-17",
      "path": "/opt/homebrew/Cellar/openjdk@17/17.0.5/libexec/openjdk.jdk/Contents/Home",
    },
    {
      "name": "JavaSE-11",
      "path": "/opt/homebrew/Cellar/openjdk@11/11.0.17/libexec/openjdk.jdk/Contents/Home",
      "default": true
    }
  ]
```

Just make sure that the configuration matches the actual versions you have installed.

Answer (score 0):

Restart VS Code, open Command Palette and choose **Java: Configure Java Runtime**, then turn to **Java Tooling Runtime**, choose openjdk17 as JDK for Language Server. Don't forget to **Reload window** to make the change effective:

[image]

The above configuration will generate `java.home` in **User Settings.json** automatically like:

```
"java.home": "C:\\Users\\Administrator\\Downloads\\openjdk-17-ea+26_windows-x64_bin\\jdk-17",
```

Try this and see if it solves your question.

Comment: Hi, I am on the M1 macbook pro, not on a windows computer. I tried this same method on macOs, but it doesnt show me any jdk in Options but I can see that Java in installed when i do ```java --version```.

Comment: @VibhoreSagar. Refer this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22842743/how-to-set-java-home-environment-variable-on-mac-os-x-10-9) to add `java_home` on your machine. then restart vscode and try again.

Comment: How do you open `Command Pallette`?