# ./gradlew The operation couldn’t be completed. Unable to locate a Java Runtime

Tags: java, macos, android-studio, gradle, gradlew

When I run `./gradlew` from project folder I get:

```
./gradlew
The operation couldn’t be completed. Unable to locate a Java Runtime.
Please visit http://www.java.com for information on installing Java.
```

The same with java:

```
which java
/usr/bin/java

/usr/bin/java
The operation couldn’t be completed. Unable to locate a Java Runtime.
Please visit http://www.java.com for information on installing Java.
```

I installed JDK in Android studio, seems it's installed in `~/Library/Android/sdk/sources/android-28`

Setting `export JAVA_HOME=/Users/mrgloom/Library/Android/sdk/sources/android-28/` or `export JAVA_HOME=/Users/mrgloom/Library/Android/sdk` produce error like:

```
ERROR: JAVA_HOME is set to an invalid directory: /Users/mrgloom/Library/Android/sdk/sources/android-28/

Please set the JAVA_HOME variable in your environment to match the
location of your Java installation.
```

How to specify java path for `gradlew` ?

Comment: The android sdk nor the android sources are a JDK

Comment: Sounds to me like you should be using `brew install openjdk@8`

Comment: Seems JDK is shipped with android studio: https://developer.android.com/studio/intro/studio-config

Comment: It is, but this is meant to be used by the IDE, only, IMO. If you are expecting to individually run Gradle or Java commands outside the IDE, then install it _outside of the IDE_

Answer (score 61, accepted):

Using JDK shipped with Android Studio and setting `export JAVA_HOME=/Applications/Android\ Studio.app/Contents/jre/Contents/Home` helped me.

Comment: In my bash profile, I had to include it with quotes instead of the backslash 
`export JAVA_HOME="/Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/jre/Contents/Home"`

Comment: Thanks guys, helped for newly installed AS without the need to install Java.

Comment: For Android Studio Electric Eel and OSX Ventura 13.1 the AS JDK was in a different ```jbr``` folder: ```export JAVA_HOME="/Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/jbr/Contents/Home"```

Answer (score 1):

Might need to clear caches and restart the studio. These steps worked for me -

1. Set Java home. You can use embedded JDK in Android Studio.

export JAVA_HOME=/Applications/Android\ Studio.app/Contents/jre/Contents/Home.

Use [Setting Java Home in MAC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22842743/how-to-set-java-home-environment-variable-on-mac-os-x-10-9) for reference if required.

2. Close terminal
3. Invalidate Caches & restart - Include 'Clear file system cache and local history'

Comment: Clearing caches and restarting the AS after setting up JAVA_HOME helped. Thanks!