# upon checking mvn version this massage pop up on Mac please need help to resolve this issue

Tags: maven, java-home

```
mvn -version
The JAVA_HOME environment variable is not defined correctly,
this environment variable is needed to run this program.
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to set JAVA\_HOME environment variable on Mac OS X 10.9?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22842743/how-to-set-java-home-environment-variable-on-mac-os-x-10-9)

Comment: echo $JAVA_HOME
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_202.jdk/Contents/Home
mohammadbhuiyan@Mohammads-MacBook-Pro ~ % mvn -version
The JAVA_HOME environment variable is not defined correctly,
this environment variable is needed to run this program.