# Error with android build while using react-native-community_geolocation

Tags: react-native, geolocation

I am using the react-native-community_geolocation package. On my IOS simulator evertging works fine but on android I keep getting a build failed.

This is the error that I get:

error Failed to install the app. Make sure you have the Android development environment set up: https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup.
Error: Command failed: ./gradlew app:installDebug -PreactNativeDevServerPort=8081

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred configuring project ':react-native-community_geolocation'.

> Could not open cp_proj generic class cache for build file '/Users/*****/Desktop/*****/node_modules/@react-native-community/geolocation/android/build.gradle' (/Users/*****/.gradle/caches/7.5.1/scripts/e08foxj1bhjhq63aa1rz2tkj3).
> BUG! exception in phase 'semantic analysis' in source unit '*BuildScript*' Unsupported class file major version 63

Can anyone help?? I can find anything on Google

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fix Java Error - Unsupported class file major version XX
The Unsupported Class File Major Version XX error indicates that the version of the Java class file that you are trying to run is not supported by the current version of the Java runtime environment (JRE) you have installed on your system.

In other words, the class file that you are trying to run was compiled using a more recent version of Java than the one you have installed.

The Unsupported Class File Major Version XX error can be fixed by updating the Java runtime environment to the latest version and ensuring that any libraries or dependencies used by the Java program are compatible with the updated JRE

In case of React Native we need to have Java 11

```
brew tap homebrew/cask-versions
brew install --cask zulu11
```

Comment: Thanks so much. How exactly would i update my java runtime environment?

Comment: @JenniferDeGoede what is result of `java -version`

Comment: java version "19.0.1" 2022-10-18
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 19.0.1+10-21)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 19.0.1+10-21, mixed mode, sharing)

Comment: @JenniferDeGoede you need version 11 for react native - follow this `brew tap homebrew/cask-versions` and
`brew install --cask zulu11`

Comment: @JenniferDeGoede you need to replace your JAVA_PATH like `export JAVA_HOME=$(/usr/libexec/java_home -v11)` and restart your terminal

Comment: @JenniferDeGoede https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22842743/how-to-set-java-home-environment-variable-on-mac-os-x-10-9

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/250578/discussion-between-kirill-novikov-and-jennifer-de-goede).