# Set JAVA_CMD_HOME for MAC

Tags: java, mechanicalturk

I'm trying to set up JAVA_CMD_HOME on a Mac (iOS 10.9) for the mTurks CLI. After I set my access keys, I've run the following in the Terminal

```
export MTURK_CMD_HOME=/users/Desktop/aws-mturk-clt-1.3.1/
export JAVA_HOME=/System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions/Current
export PATH=$PATH:/users/Desktop/aws-mturk-clt-1.3.1/bin
```

When I run:

```
/users/Desktop/aws-mturk-clt-1.3.1/bin/getBalance.sh
```

I get the following error:

```
/users/Desktop/aws-mturk-clt-1.3.1//bin/invoke.sh: line 79: /System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions/Current/bin/java: No such file or directory
```

How do I set this directory?

Comment: I believe you are asking for `JAVA_HOME` instead of `JAVA_CMD_HOME`? Have a look in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1348842/what-should-i-set-java-home-to-on-osx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this to find the system java installs:

```
$ /usr/libexec/java_home
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_25.jdk/Contents/Home
```

so in your script / .bash_rc file:

```
$ export JAVA_HOME=$(/usr/libexec/java_home)
```

Comment: When I change the file path, I get:
`log4j:ERROR setFile(null,true) call failed.
java.io.FileNotFoundException: ../log/aws-mturk-clt.log (No such file or directory)log4j:ERROR setFile(null,true) call failed.
java.io.FileNotFoundException: ../log/aws-mturk-clt.log (No such file or directory)` and `There was a problem reading your properties file from mturk.properties.The exception was java.io.FileNotFoundException: mturk.properties (No such file or directory)
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Cannot load configuration properties file from mturk.properties`

Comment: that's great! Java is now working, plz accept the answer :). Also put your properties files in the correct directories

Comment: I've added a new [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28534369/specify-cli-path-for-mturk-for-mac). Please help if you can.