# Meteor 1.1 - JDK error when installing Android SDK

Tags: cordova, meteor

When I run the command `meteor install-sdk android`, I get the following message:

```
✓ Found Android bundle
✗ A JDK is not installed                      
✓ Android emulator acceleration is installed
```

I know what you're thinking: "Have you installed the JDK?" Yes I have. I downloaded the JDK from Oracle and installed it. When I run the command `java -version`, I get the following output:

```
java version "1.8.0_45"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_45-b14)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.45-b02, mixed mode)
```

Something tells me that there is path wrong somewhere, but I don't know where to start looking for it. Any ideas are welcome! I'm running OSX.

Answer (score 0):

You probably just need to set your `JAVA_HOME` environmental variable to your JDK installation. As describe [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1348842/what-should-i-set-java-home-to-on-osx):

```
export JAVA_HOME=$(/usr/libexec/java_home)
```

Comment: I think you might be right. Currently, `JAVA_HOME` is set to `JAVA_HOME=/usr`.

Comment: Unfortunately... I still don't know where jdk1.8 lives. I did some Googling and found that it installs itself here: `/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_45.jdk/`, but setting the environment variable to that path doesn't work. Any thoughts on how I can find out where the proper version of JDK lives?