# Maven project installation: invalid target release: 1.7 error

Tags: java, maven

I'm having this error when i try to install a project using maven.
I read a lot of posts saying that this error is because maven is using another version of java but this is not my case (i think) because every command i run says that the version used is java 1.7.

This is the results of the terminal:

```
Maven installation error:
Failure executing javac, but could not parse the error:
javac: invalid target release: 1.7
Usage: javac <options> <source files>
use -help for a list of possible options
```

Output of mvn -version

```
Apache Maven 3.1.1 (0728685237757ffbf44136acec0402957f723d9a; 2013-09-17 12:22:22-0300)
Maven home: /Applications/Dev/apache-maven-3.3.3
Java version: 1.7.0_79, vendor: Oracle Corporation
Java home: /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_79.jdk/Contents/Home/jre
Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: UTF-8
OS name: "mac os x", version: "10.11.1", arch: "x86_64", family: "mac"
```

Java home:
`/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_79.jdk/Contents/Home`

pom.xml (compiler plugin section):

```
<plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.7</source>
                    <target>1.7</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
```

Everything looks fine to me but keep getting the error.

Comment: Please use an up-to-date version of the [maven-compiler-plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/) (3.3) than this should work..

Comment: How do i update the maven compiler plugin?

Comment: How do you call Maven? From Command line or from within IDE?

Answer (score 2):

Update `maven-compiler-plugin` version to **3.3**:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.3</version> <!--  HERE  -->
    <configuration>
        <source>1.7</source>
        <target>1.7</target>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

How is the `JAVA_HOME` set?

> Java home: /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_79.jdk/Contents/Home/jre

Look like you need to correct this to `/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_79.jdk/`

[Why I am not able to see the JAVA_HOME path on my MAC OS X 10.11?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33046697/why-i-am-not-able-to-see-the-java-home-path-on-my-mac-os-x-10-11)

Comment: That doesn't solve the problem... keep showing the same error

Comment: JAVA_HOME throws `/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_79.jdk/Contents/Home` but in `mvn -version` throws `/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_79.jdk/Contents/Home/jre` is the JAVA_HOME the first or the second?

Comment: Check update in answer. I guess you are on OS-X v10.11