# Setting $JAVA_HOME correctly on Mac OS

Tags: java, macos, path, environment-variables

I am trying to get maven working on mac but it complains about not being able to locate $JAVA_HOME, so I set up the env variable in the following way

e`xport JAVA_HOME = $(/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_31.jdk/Contents/Home)`

I get maven working with this, but evey time I start a shell I get the following error

```
-bash: /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_31.jdk/Contents/Home: No such file or directory
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: Your export statement shouldn't have the `$()` around the value; if you echo it I find it hard to believe it's actually working. Or use `$()` around the `java_home` command.

Comment: Hi Dave, without the $(), maven could not locate $JAVA_HOME

Comment: Then something is wrong with your Maven, your shell, or something else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your question, the command shows spaces around the '=' sign in the assignment, which will mess it up.

The assignment should look like this:

```
export JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_31.jdk/Contents/Home
```

You definitely shouldn't have the `$(...)` around it - that tries to execute the text inside the parentheses, which is why you get that "No such file or directory" error. Perhaps that came from trying to use examples which show how to execute the OSX `java_home` command, as shown in the answer to this question:
[What should I set JAVA_HOME to on OSX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1348842/what-should-i-set-java-home-to-on-osx)

Answer (score 0):

Can you try the following `export JAVA_HOME=`/usr/libexec/java_home -v 1.8.0_73` ? Also see this [What should I set JAVA_HOME to on OSX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1348842/what-should-i-set-java-home-to-on-osx)

p.s. - Adjust the commands for the java versions available on your machine