# Error: JAVA_HOME is not defined correctly, when installing Maven on Mac

Tags: macos, maven

It is suppose to be easy, but I'm having great difficulty installing Maven on to my mac 10.11.4.

I have created M2_HOME and PATH for Maven, but when I type in `mvn --version`, the terminal tell me

```
/Users/justin/apache-maven-3.3.9/bin/mvn: line 53: uname: command not found
/Users/justin/apache-maven-3.3.9/bin/mvn: line 143: which: command not found
/Users/justin/apache-maven-3.3.9/bin/mvn: line 171: which: command not found
Error: JAVA_HOME is not defined correctly.
  We cannot execute
```

Why is this happening?

[image]

Comment: Hmm, if `uname` and `which` are not defined, that's rather strange. I would be very surprised if they do not work on a Mac. Do they work on your console at all? These are core commands that should work everywhere, even without Java or Maven installed. What does `echo $PATH` give you?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need `JAVA_HOME` to be defined, as covered in [installation guide](https://maven.apache.org/install.html).

Check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1348842/what-should-i-set-java-home-to-on-osx) for additional details for MacOS.

Comment: the installation guide simply said "Ensure JAVA_HOME environment variable is set and points to your JDK installation", but it does not give you details on how to do so, especially for complete noobs like me

Answer (score 4):

For macOs Ventura 13.1

If you installed java openJdk version 11 using Homebrew:

```
brew install java11
```

Then, your java is installed on:

```
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/openjdk@11/11.0.17/libexec/openjdk.jdk/Contents/Home
```

So, you must understand that this is you JAVA_HOME environment variable.

You need to add the java '/bin' folder to your PATH environment variable in order to have it working on your terminal. Also, you need to create the JAVA_HOME environment variable in order to maven to know about your java.

Therefore, you must open:

```
/Users/<yourUser>/.zshrc
```

Add

```
export JAVA_HOME="/opt/homebrew/Cellar/openjdk@11/11.0.17/libexec/openjdk.jdk/Contents/Home"
export PATH="/opt/homebrew/opt/openjdk@11/bin:$PATH"
```

Save your changes, close the file. Now you can open your terminal and type:

```
java -version
```

and then,

```
mvn -version
```

and this is what you should get:

```
example@example441 ~ % java -version
openjdk version "11.0.17" 2022-10-18
OpenJDK Runtime Environment Homebrew (build 11.0.17+0)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM Homebrew (build 11.0.17+0, mixed mode)

example@example441 ~ % mvn -version
Apache Maven 3.8.7 (xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx)
Maven home: /opt/homebrew/Cellar/maven/3.8.7/libexec
Java version: 11.0.17, vendor: Homebrew, runtime: 
opt/homebrew/Cellar/openjdk@11/11.0.17/libexec/openjdk.jdk/Contents/Home
Default locale: pt_BR, platform encoding: UTF-8
OS name: "mac os x", version: "13.1", arch: "aarch64", family: "mac"
```

Answer (score 0):

Install using homebrew https://formulae.brew.sh/formula/openjdk

```
brew install openjdk@21
```

OR

```
brew install openjdk@11
```

Then set up the .profile on your mac (/Users/your_username/.profile). If this file is hidden you may need to press ***Command + Shift + . (the period key)*** to make it visible.

add **JAVA_HOME** and update the **PATH** variable

```
export JAVA_HOME=$(/usr/libexec/java_home)
export PATH="$JAVA_HOME:$PATH"
```

open new terminal and type

```
echo $JAVA_HOME
echo $PATH
```

to verify your change.