# Set JAVA_HOME PATH for java 1.8 OSX sierra not work

Tags: java, macos, path, macos-sierra

I check my last install java using this command line:

```
$ java -version
```

and output is:

```
java version "1.8.0_121"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_121-b13)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.121-b13, mixed mode)
```

But in `echo $JAVA_HOME`:

```
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/Contents/Home
```

How do can i set `$JAVA_HOME` PATH for java version `1.8`?

Comment: Duplicate of [What should I set JAVA_HOME to on OSX](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1348842/what-should-i-set-java-home-to-on-osx) ?

Comment: Add export JAVA_HOME=$(/usr/libexec/java_home) to .bashrc or .zshrc file. Start bash/zsh prompt again.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about Mac. But in linux which is very simliar I do something like this in my `.bashrc` and `.bash_profile`. Here you can see where I have set my JAVA_HOME. After modified those files you will have to logout and them login for the path to take affect.

```
# .bashrc

# Source global definitions
if [ -f /etc/bashrc ]; then
    . /etc/bashrc
fi

# Uncomment the following line if you don't like systemctl's auto-paging feature:
# export SYSTEMD_PAGER=

# User specific aliases and functions
export JAVA_HOME=/home/steve/.local/share/android-studio/jre
export GRADLE_HOME=/opt/gradle/gradle/bin
export ADB=/home/steve/Android/Sdk/platform-tools
export ANDROID_HOME=/home/steve/Android/Sdk
```

And

```
# .bash_profile

# Get the aliases and functions
if [ -f ~/.bashrc ]; then
    . ~/.bashrc
fi

# User specific environment and startup programs

PATH=$PATH:$HOME/.local/bin:$HOME/bin:$JAVA_HOME/bin:$ADB:$ANDROID_HOME

export PATH
```