# Failed to find 'JAVA_HOME' environment variable in Mac

Tags: java, node.js, git, cordova, java-home

I'm new on Mac, so I installed Cordova (Node, Git, Grandle) but I can't execute it in my mobile phone, I mean I can't do "sudo Cordova run android" because it can't find "JAVA_HOME". When I installed I put this variable before... (It is a headache )

I tried to open the bash_profile but I didn't find it and if I open in terminal it always open a new file.

If I do echo $JAVA_HOME, it is the result:

```
echo $JAVA_HOME
```

/usr/libexec/java_home

And this is my error:

```
sudo cordova run android --target=ZY223T38PM
```

> (node:1369) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: CordovaError: Failed to find 'JAVA_HOME' environment variable. Try setting setting it manually.
> at /Users/tonitorres/Dropbox/HardwareHome/hardwareHome/platforms/android/cordova/lib/check_reqs.js:185:35
> at _rejected (/Users/tonitorres/Dropbox/HardwareHome/hardwareHome/platforms/android/cordova/node_modules/q/q.js:864:24)
> at /Users/tonitorres/Dropbox/HardwareHome/hardwareHome/platforms/android/cordova/node_modules/q/q.js:890:30
> at Promise.when (/Users/tonitorres/Dropbox/HardwareHome/hardwareHome/platforms/android/cordova/node_modules/q/q.js:1142:31)
> at Promise.promise.promiseDispatch (/Users/tonitorres/Dropbox/HardwareHome/hardwareHome/platforms/android/cordova/node_modules/q/q.js:808:41)
> at /Users/tonitorres/Dropbox/HardwareHome/hardwareHome/platforms/android/cordova/node_modules/q/q.js:624:44
> at runSingle (/Users/tonitorres/Dropbox/HardwareHome/hardwareHome/platforms/android/cordova/node_modules/q/q.js:137:13)
> at flush (/Users/tonitorres/Dropbox/HardwareHome/hardwareHome/platforms/android/cordova/node_modules/q/q.js:125:13)
> at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:131:7)
> at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:180:9)
> (node:1369) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 1)
> (node:1369) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.

Comment: set up JAVA_HOME to point to the directory where your JAVA installation resides and then try

Comment: what is output after executing `java -version` in terminal?

Comment: @nazar_art It says that I need to install JDK, but I swear I installed it, well I am going to install it and say something

Comment: @nazar_art I have Android Studio and it functions perfectly with java, and have sdk... so I don't understand.

Comment: now it says that it require jdk 1.8 or greater but I installed the salt version

Comment: Why are `git` and `cordova` tagged in this?

Comment: set JAVA_HOME environment variable which points to the directory where Java is installed and then try again.

Comment: Someone know about this error? (node:8132) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: spawn EACCES

Comment: @evolutionxbox because the project I'm trying to run is doing with Cordova, git and node.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You didn't install `JAVA_HOME` correctly, therefore it fails.

You have to do it like following:

- [10 JDK 8 Installation for OS X](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/install/mac_jdk.html)

After installation you have to add installed java to system variable:

- [How to Set $JAVA_HOME environment variable on Mac OS X](https://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-set-java_home-environment-variable-on-mac-os-x/)
- [What should I set JAVA_HOME to on OSX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1348842/what-should-i-set-java-home-to-on-osx)

Run in terminal for verification:

`java -version`

The output should be something like:

```
java version "1.8.0_06-ea"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_06-ea-b13)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 23.2-b04, mixed mode)
```

After this check, you can import java to your IDE.