# Why my mac is not displaying java version?

Tags: java, macos

Our help desk already installed Java 1.8_151 on our macbook pro Mohave.
When I type 'which java' I get the reply as **/usr/bin/java**

So, I added these two lines in my .bash_profile file in my home folder /Users/pnutalap

```
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/bin/java
export PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH
```

When I checked immediately 'java -version' I got back the java version correctly.
But today, I am getting totally different resonse like...

> N201960-MAC:~ pnutalap$ java -v Unable to locate an executable at
>   "/usr/bin/java/bin/java" (-1)

Why there is additional /java at the end ?
What has gone wrong ? And how to correct it to show java version properly ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What should I set JAVA\_HOME to on OSX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1348842/what-should-i-set-java-home-to-on-osx)

Comment: Probably your `PATH` is messed up, because `export` execute everytime it's called. My tip is to echo `PATH` (a clean one possibly) to a new env var (like `DEFAULT_PATH`) and then exporting `PATH` in bash_aliases **without** concatenating `PATH` with itself, but joining `DEFAULT_PATH` and `JAVA_HOME`

Answer (score 0):

When I tried to move to /usr/bin/java, I got the reply

**N201960-MAC:~ pnutalap$** cd /usr/bin/java
-bash: cd: /usr/bin/java: **Not a directory**

Looks like within /usr/bin/ folder, the 'java' is not a directory, but a symbolic link. Now it makes sense why it is trying to say `Unable to locate an executable at "/usr/bin/java/bin/java"` simply going by the PATH variable.